# react navigation open screen in landscape

Tags: android, ios, react-native, orientation, react-navigation-v5

I am using `react-navigation` v5. All my app is in portrait but 2 screens in landscape mode. I have a custom player and youtube embedded player which should rotate. My custom player can be only in landscape mode. My player is a modal screen. I want it to be in landscape mode only and other screens under it in portrait how can I do that? Because right now my whole app changes orientation with `react-native-orientation-locker` lib.

example code:

```js
export default class Player extends Component<PlayerProps, PlayerState> {
  state = {
    paused: false,
    progress: 0,
    duration: 0,
    currentQuality: '',
  };

...

  componentDidMount() {
    // this locks the view to Portrait Mode

    Orientation.lockToLandscape();
    StatusBar.setHidden(true);

    // this locks the view to Landscape Mode
    // Orientation.lockToLandscape();

    // this unlocks any previous locks to all Orientations
    // Orientation.unlockAllOrientations();

    Orientation.addOrientationListener(this._orientationDidChange);
  }

  _orientationDidChange = (orientation: string) => {
    if (orientation === 'LANDSCAPE') {
      // do something with landscape layout
    } else {
      // do something with portrait layout
    }
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Orientation.lockToPortrait();
    StatusBar.setHidden(false);
    Orientation.getOrientation((err, orientation) => {
      console.log(`Current Device Orientation: ${orientation}`);
    });

    // Remember to remove a listener
    Orientation.removeOrientationListener(this._orientationDidChange);
  }

 ...

  render() {
    return (...);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Were you able to figure out a good solution to this? I tried this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#orientation, but it isn't working. Here's a snack: https://snack.expo.dev/9LZ5ItpXl.

Comment: Actually, it looks like Android works with that setting, but not iOS.